# Complex analysis with logarithms

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

Question: If $\Im z_{1} > 0$ and $\Im z_{2} > 0$, does $Log(z_{1}z_{2}) = Log z_{1} + Log z_{2}$?

If yes, prove the statement.
If no, give a counterexample.

My approach:
Suppose that  $\Im z_{1} > 0$ and $\Im z_{2} > 0$, then

$z_{1} = r_{1}\exp i  \theta_{1}$ and $z_{2} = r_{2}\exp i  \theta_{2}$

where $0<\theta_{1}<\pi$ and $0<\theta_{2}<\pi$

Thus, $0<\theta_{1} + \theta_{2}<2\pi$

Thus, $Log(z_{1}z_{2}) = Log[(r_{1}r_{2})\exp i  (\theta_{1} + \theta_{2})] = Log(r_{1}r_{2}) + i  (\theta_{1} + \theta_{2})$

What should I do next to prove that the statement is true? I'm not sure if it is true but cannot find a counterargument.

Thank you so much for your help!

P/S: The principal value of $log z$ is $Log z$.
Please do not edit when you don't know the actual terms.

Comment: What is $\operatorname{Log}$?

Comment: Hint: is it always true that $Arg(z_1z_2)=Arg(z_1)+Arg(z_2)$?

Comment: It seems (perhaps wrongly to me) that you have adopted the conventions that [1] for $z \in \Bbb{C}, z \neq 0,$ Arg$(z) \in (-\pi, \pi]$ and [2] for $0 \neq z = \left(re^{i\theta}\right), ~r > 0, \theta \in (-\pi,\pi],~~$ you have that $\text{Log}(z) = \log(r) + i\theta$.  The problem then is brought into focus directly by the comment above, of @zugzug.

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos The principal value of log z is Log z.

Comment: You can find counterexamples by choosing $z_1$ and $z_2$ in the second quadrant, e.g. $z_1 =z_2 = -1 + i$.

Comment: @hanamontana: Why not? The imaginary part of $\operatorname{Log}(z_1) + \operatorname{Log}(z_2)$ is $3 \pi /4 +  3 \pi/ 4 = 3 \pi/2$, and the imaginary part of $\operatorname{Log}(z_1 z_2) = \operatorname{Log}(-2i)$ is $-\pi/2$.

Comment: @MartinR sorry i mistyped the answers. I've deleted the comment right after but it still showed up. Thanks for the answer!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The principal value of the complex logarithm and the principal value of the argument of non-zero complex numbers are connected via
$$
 \DeclareMathOperator{Log}{Log}
 \DeclareMathOperator{Arg}{Arg}
\Log(z) = \log |z| + i \Arg(z) \, ,
$$
so the question whether
$$ \tag{1}
 \Log(z_1 z_2) = \Log(z_1) + \Log(z_2)
$$
holds or not is equivalent to asking if
$$ \tag{2}
 \Arg(z_1 z_2) = \Arg(z_1) + \Arg(z_2)
$$
holds or not.

The number on the right-hand side of $(2)$ is *an* argument of $z_1 z_2$, and $\Arg(z)$ is usually defined as the argument in the range $(-\pi, \pi]$. This means that $(2)$ and $(1)$ hold if and only if
$$
 -\pi < \Arg(z_1) + \Arg(z_2) \le \pi \, .
$$

You have restricted $z_1$ and $z_2$ to the upper half-plane $\Im(z) > 0$, but that is not sufficient to make $(1)$ and $(2)$ hold. We can still find numbers whose arguments add up to a value larger than $\pi$, e.g. by picking both numbers in the second quadrant.

A simple counterexample is $z_1 = z_2 = -1 + i$.